# PHP control operator (@) doesn't work

Tags: php, operators

The [control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is used to make all warnings/errors silent, no matter what the consequences are. I would like to use this crazy tool, but I guess I've got some strange server configuration and - even though I add @ to a function, it still throws warnings/errors:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $f = @file('juzio');
PHP Warning:  file(juzio): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. file() php shell code:1
```

I've been trying to find a setting that is responsibe for this, but found nothing so far. Anybody knows why @ isn't working for me? Just in case, I'm running PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch. I've got also xdebug installed (in case it matters).

---

edit: please don't write about `error_reporting`. My question is about `@` operator. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to display errors, turn off error reporting. Don't use `@`.

Comment: learn more about @ [http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: @AmalMurali `@` is useful if you just want to suppress errors for a single call, not the entire script.

Comment: Why would someone like to suppress the error, its like flying a plane even when the control room knows that weather is bad..

Comment: @AmalMurali I know `error_reporting`. this is not what I want. I want to check my `@` isn't working.
@nurakantech if you read my question precisely, I linked that page. And there's nothing there about any .ini settings (which I expect). Btw, php.net's description of `@` is different than it works for me right now - I get the errors printed all the time.

Comment: @Barmar: I think suppressing errors is a fundamental mistake. Why not just create an error handler, or use exceptions. Don't hide the error, fix/handle it instead.

Comment: @Mr.Alien please, quit offtopic. I'm asking why isn't it working, not what can I use it for.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Are you, by chance, using a Scream extension?

Comment: @AmalMurali I grepped my xdebug.ini and found `xdebug.scream=1`

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Set it to 0.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Aha! That'd certainly do it - the whole purpose of the "scream" option is to un-suppress all errors.

Comment: @AmalMurali please write the scream stuff as an answer and I'll accept that. Congratulations and many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scream.enabled` directive in your `php.ini` configuration file will disable the effects of error suppression operator (`@`):

Quoting the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.scream.php):

> The scream extension gives the possibility to disable the silencing error control operator so all errors are being reported. This feature is controlled by an ini setting.

See the example from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/scream.examples-simple.php) to understand how it affects error reporting.

Disabling `scream` should fix the issue.

Change the directive in your `php.ini`, like so:

```
scream.enabled = 0
```

If you want to disable it during run-time, then you can use `ini_set` as stated in the manual:

```
ini_set('scream.enabled', false);
```

Comment: in my case it was precisely `xdebug.scream` set to 1

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Glad to know you figured it out :)