# Is it normal for "@file_get_contents" to produce DEBUG line in log

Tags: php

I have this line of code (actually it's Magento not mine):

`$ids = @file_get_contents($this->_tagFile($tag));`

And sometimes file doesn't exist, and this line throws a:

```
DEBUG (7): file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory/
```

Shouldn't it be supressed, and shouldn't the line just return false? Is it expected for this to produce a DEBUG-level entry in the log?

Comment: If you added a custom error handler function, it could appear in your error log. The same thing happens with the CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: Do you have [scream extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19339587/1438393) enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Magento user, but it seems reasonable that something like that would have its own [custom error handler](http://php.net/set-error-handler). Of particular note is that @-suppressed errors are *still sent* to the error handler, but with an error level of zero.

Normally you would check the error level against the `error_reporting` directive to see if it should be handled or not, but in this case I would imagine Magento is logging suppressed errors as "DEBUG-level", with the specific purpose of silently ignoring them as far as the forward-facing site goes, while still keeping track of them so you can track down such potentially unexpected behaviour.

Comment: makes sense. Basically I'm wondering if all those logged lines are normal behaviour, but since the rest of the code allows for the returned value to be false, I'm guessing it is, and the whole thing just should have been programmed a bit better by checking the file for existence first.

Comment: @Netismine "and the whole thing just should have been programmed a bit better by checking the file for existence first" -- Yup! In fact I'm surprised you don't have an angry mob telling you not to use `@`. Personally, I use it sparingly, on things where I can't know ahead of time if it'll work or not, such as `fsockopen`.